# Wordpress Woocommerce 2nd sql database connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have just transferred a backup of a WordPress site to a new domain. I loaded all of the sites files using FTP and I connected the main database (called `boxedsco_master.sql`) to the new site's database using phpMyAdmin. The new prefix for the databases is "`boxeipxy_`" rather than "`boxedsco_`". I also updated `wp-config.php` to connect the master database, which worked fine.

However there was also a second database called `boxedsco_boxes.sql`. Which I also uploaded using phpMyAdmin, and is now called "`boxeipxy_boxes.sql`".

The site is mainly working, however, there are no notification emails when an order is placed, either to me customer or my client. I believe this could be because the second database is not correctly connected, as the database contains tables called things like "`wp_easycontactforms_customforms`".

How do I connect this second database? Would there be a php file to update with the new database name? I can't find a php file that references "`boxedsco_boxes.sql`" in order to update it?

Using **Wordpress 3.8.5** and **WooCommerce 2.0.20**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No wonder no-one responded! There should not be 2 databases! I thought it was very strange!

The email notifications issue was a bug with woocommerce not liking the send-from address! Changing it to "wordpress@[yourdomain].com" fixed the issue completely!

Thanks anyway folks!

Answer (score 0):

the fact that you have a two files with .sql suffixes doesn't mean there are two databases.  Crack open the files and look inside.   They are most likely two dumps from the same database; have a look if they contain the same data and/or tables or not.

As the philosopher says, "a poem about the moon is not moon".  A sqldump isn't a database, it's a "representation" of a database.  Most likely you have two poems about the same moon.